# Django admin translate

Tags: django, django-admin, translation

I want my admin in Turkish. So I set *LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr-TR'* and USE_I18N = True But django admin still in english. 
Is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 1):

Since the admin is basically just a normal Django app, the usual [rules for language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/deployment/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)  apply. I suppose Turkish isn't set as the preferred language in your browser.

In case you want to explicitly set the language for the admin, you might want to have a look at this middleware:
http://source.mihelac.org/2009/11/12/django-set-language-for-admin/